# What is the area of the part of the plane $2x + 2y - z = 10$ that lies in the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the area of the part of the plane $2x + 2y - z = 10$ that lies in the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$.

What can I use to solve this? Can I use the Green's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Think about projecting onto the $xy$-plane. What is the relation between the two areas? **Hint**: The angle between the two planes is relevant.